# How do I make a 'New Window' function in the menu bar of a Cocoa Application?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm very new to OS X development and I'm trying to make a rudimentary text editor. I would like for the user to be able to open multiple windows of text editing at once, not unlike textedit. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It's a bit more advanced than a beginner topic, but for this sort of application you should consider making it "document-based". See the [Document-Based App Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html). Also, the [source for TextEdit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TextEdit/Introduction/Intro.html) is available as a learning tool.

Answer (score 0):

This very well depends on if you're using XIBs, Storyboards or pure code. But in all it's simplicity, all you do is to create another `NSWindow` instance, and show it, ie.:

```
NSWindow *window = [NSWindow alloc] init]
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```